# How is this variable keeping track of the current index? Someone please explain

Tags: javascript, arrays

The exercise in the book shows this code below to sort out the scores and display all of them in the log.
I don't understand why i = 0 or how i is "keeping track of the current index" as the exercise shows.

```
var scores = [ 60, 50, 60, 54, 54, 58, 50, 52, 54, 48, 69,
            34, 55, 51, 52, 44, 51, 69, 64, 66, 55, 52, 61, 46,
             31, 57, 52, 44, 18, 41, 53, 55, 61, 51, 44]

var output; 

var i = 0;


while (i <scores.length) {

    output = "Bubble solution # " + i + "score: " + scores [i];

    console.log(output);

    i = i + 1; 

}
```

Comment: The key is `i = i + 1;` ... increments `i` every iteration of the loop

Comment: Thank you. so the initial value for i is 0 which is clear. But how does it increment the index of the array? Is it because it's in the (i <scores.length)?

Comment: No `(i <scores.length)` is the condition that stops the loop when `i` gets to array length. Add a `console.log(i)` at bottom of the loop and you will see how it gets incremented

Comment: `var i = 0` sets i to zero. `i = i + 1` increments `i` by one. It sets `i` to the old value of `i` and then adds one. So if `i` is `0`, the equation is `i = 0 + 1`, so in the next run `i` is `1`. Then in this next run the equation is `i = 1 + 1`. So for the run after this run, `i` is `2`. And so on.

Answer (score 1):

`var i = 0;` This part resets the variable to `0`

As `0` is the first index of an array, it ensures that you will always fetch the first element of an array when using `array[i]` which is `array[0]`

At the end of each `while` iteration, it increments the index in order to get the next object in the array: `i = i + 1;`

Since `i` has now been increased, `array[i]` will now be `array[1]` which represents the second element in the array.

This repeats until the initial condition (`i < scores.length`) is no longer true

Comment: Thank you so much! Beginner questions I know :)